# Logical conditions with missing values

Tags: spss

I'm using Transform > Compute Variable to OR two variables (B,C) together. My two vars can have values 1, 2, or 3. I want to calculate a third var that's 1 if either B or C is 1 and zero otherwise. This works

```
A = (B=1) | (C=1)
```

But I'm running into trouble if B or C is missing. What I'd like is

```
if B and C exist and B or C equals 1, A = 1
if B and C exist and neither equals 1, A = 0
if B is missing and C is missing, A = missing
if B or C is 1 and the other value is missing, A = 1
if B or C is not 1 and the other value is missing, A = 0
```

Can I use Transform > Compute Variable to accomplish this or do I need another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one liner for this:

```
compute A=max((B=1), (C=1)).
exe.
```

You can do this through the transformation menus, but I recommend getting used to (the power of) using syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this in the syntax window. `If variable exists` is translated as `if ~miss(variable)`

```
if ~miss(B) and ~miss(C) and any(1,B,C) A=1.
if ~miss(B) and ~miss(C) and ~any(1,B,C) A=0.
if miss(B) and miss(C) A=$sysmis.
if miss(B) or miss(C) and any(1,B,C) A=1.
if miss(B) or miss(C) and ~any(1,B,C) A=0.
EXECUTE.
```

Or, if I understand correctly what you are trying to do:

```
Compute A=0.
if any(1,B,C) A=1.
if miss(A) and miss(B) A=$sysmis.
EXECUTE.
```